# Why is the value of y bar larger than the actual range of y in stacked bar plot?

Tags: bar-chart

I am trying to plot the stacked bar plot for the data frame, with x equals to the year release, and y equals to count. But why the range of y in the plot is almost 1000? The largest count value should be 33.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IymC.png)